# Docker Graceful Shutdown from Dotnet Core 2.0 app

Tags: docker, .net-core

I have a .NET Core 2.0 console app running in a local Docker Linux container (Docker CE 18.03.1 stable channel) and am trying to handle a graceful shutdown.

My app has handlers for both `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit` and `AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Unloading`:

```
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += CurrentDomain_ProcessExit;
        AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Unloading += Default_Unloading;
```

The handlers simply write log messages when called.

I find that, when I do a `docker stop <containerid>`, *neither* handler is called and after a short delay. The container simply stops running. I've tried debugging the app in Visual Studio and have tried running without the debugger. In all cases, the handlers aren't getting called.

Is there some other magic incantation that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this behaviour.

This is the code I used in a console app:

```
    private static readonly AutoResetEvent _closing = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += CurrentDomain_ProcessExit;
        AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Unloading += Default_Unloading;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        });
        Console.CancelKeyPress += new ConsoleCancelEventHandler(OnExit);
        _closing.WaitOne();
    }

    private static void Default_Unloading(AssemblyLoadContext obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("unload");
    }

    private static void CurrentDomain_ProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("process exit");
    }

    protected static void OnExit(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exit");
        _closing.Set();
    }
```

With this docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy and build everything else
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "out/shutdown.dll"]
```

This is the output: (with `docker stop <id>`)

```
06/01/2018 16:31:16
06/01/2018 16:31:17
06/01/2018 16:31:18
unload
process exit
```

I'm using Docker for Windows with a Linux container.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was able to get the expected result from your example code but not from my own (nearly identical) code; I'm still trying to figure out what's different. The main difference is that I used the VS2017 "Add Docker Support" option which generated a Dockerfile and added a docker-compose "project" to my solution. Functionally, they seem to be about the same as your sample but operationally, they're very different. Will update when I get to the bottom of it.

Comment: I tried now with vs 2017 and with "Add Docker Support" and this also works for me. I had problems debugging it from vs but this is a different story. Are you using release build of your application to try it from console? Because if you build it in debug it does nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Very strange behavior.
I was having the same issue and for me it turned out that it does **NOT work** when I use the following entrypoint in the dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT dotnet DockerTest.dll
```

When I change it to the following, it **works**:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerTest.dll"]
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: This won't work well. There's no guarantee that using that ENTRYPOINT will force the container to be always opened.